# React Native Module cannot find type RCTPromiseResolveBlock not in scope

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, native

I am new to building modules in react native and trying to build a native module with react native module, for some reason I get. I have googled online and it says just add the imports to your bridging file to expose object-c code to swift but seems its not happening for me. not sure if i missed something or i am missing something.

```
cannot find type 'RCTPromiseRejectBlock' in scope
cannot find type 'RCTPromiseResolveBlock' in scope
```

I included <React/RCTBridgeModule.h> in my `AppName-Bridging-Header.m` file but still same result, i have removed all node_modules, podfile and rebuild and still same problem.

```
# App-Bridging-Header.m
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>
```

```
ModuleFile.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(Vgas, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(multiply:(float)a withB:(float)b
                 withResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 withRejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)

@end
```

```
#swift file
import Foundation

@objc(Vgas)
class Vgas: NSObject {

    @objc(multiply:withB:withResolver:withRejecter:)
    func multiply(a: Float, b: Float, resolve:RCTPromiseResolveBlock,reject:RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
        resolve(a*b)
    }
}
```

[image]